# making a link using jquery on images

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a code where i need to create a href link to the images too. with the following screenshot

http://prntscr.com/iqo2ad

i tried it something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   var link = $(".car-image").find('li:first').find('a').attr('href');
   var appendtoimg = $('.car-image').closest('.img-responsive') - here i am stuck as i need to add an onclick event so it can work same as like <a> tag
});
```

Comment: im confused as to what you're actuall asking?

Comment: provide more detail please, and some examples of what you are trying to achieve

Comment: Your code will not work this way because there are multiple car-images. you need to use link.each(function(){}) and in the function you migth want to wrap an `a` tag around the image or you add a click ahandle that sets window.location.href.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using jquery you can add a click event listener.

```
$(".car-image").click(function(){ });
```